# how to share to facebook without showing feed dialog in android application?

Tags: facebook

I tried a lot about sharing to facebook without showing dialog using facebook android sdk,but could not get solution. Please help me to share to facebook without dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GraphReqest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/). This code posts a Bitmap image on facebook with caption using facebook sdk 4.2

```
    Bitmap bmp;
    String caption;

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    final JSONObject graphObject=new JSONObject();
        Callback callback=new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {               
            // your code                
        }
    };

    GraphRequest request=GraphRequest.newPostRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me/photos", graphObject, callback);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    //params.putString("method", "photos.upload");          
    params.putString("caption", caption);
    params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);

    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();
```

You will have to take **publish_actions** permissions from the user

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

Moreover, If your app requires **publish_actions**, then you also need to send your app for the review on fb developers page, otherwise it will only work for developer accounts and tester accounts.

Comment: Facebook has done away with the publish_actions permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-24-2018